# How to show all values of an oledb data source in a table?

Tags: oledb, livecycle-designer

I'm new to livecylce designer and since I can't find an answer to this simple question or the provided answers end up unsuccessfully in my case, I hope I can get some help here.

So all I wanna do is, showing all the values of a OLEDB data sources in a table. My problem is that only one row is shown in the table. I tried to wrap it in a subform, choose content 'flowed', and set the rows to repeat for every item. But it won't change anything. And yes I'm sure the query provides 2 rows and 3 columns, or at least thats whats returned in mssql.

Maybe I missed some fundamental understanding how this is supposed to work. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Thanks Alex

Comment: please post your code that you have tried. You could also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MatthewD, thanks for your reply. I flollowed the following guide: [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/DesignerHelp/WS92d06802c76abadb-5ec05741129b8b006dd-7fc2.html). So I am not using any code. Do you mean the automatically created XML source code?

Comment: hi, finally I found a solution here: [link](http://forms.stefcameron.com/2006/10/12/displaying-all-records-from-an-odbc-data-connection/), my mistake was to use an approach which is only possible for XML schema's or at least thats my understanding.